# Spring Security - Localized Messages

Tags: java, spring-security, localization, message

I'm trying to localize the messages thrown by Spring Security. I'm using Spring 4.3.1 and Spring Security 4.1.1.
The localization of other values using messages.properties is working fine, only the Spring Security messages do not work properly. I get all the time the same message regardless of the language (in my case I get all the time the german message ("Benutzername oder Passwort falsch")). Is there something that I forgot to configure?

**snippet from mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames" value="messages"/>
</bean>
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver"/>
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language"/>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

**loadByUsername method (if needed)**

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DisabledException {
    Member member = memberDao.getMember(username);
    if (member == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user not found...");
    } ...
```

**web.xml**

```
<!--DispatcherServlet-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!--ContextLoaderListener-->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Spring Security Chain Filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**messages_de.properties**

```
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials=Benutzername oder Passwort falsch
field.username=Benutzername
```

**messages_en.properties**

```
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials=Wrong username or password
field.username=Username
```

Comment: check this link http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-i18n-and-localization-i10n-example/

Comment: With this config the "normal" localization (field names, etc.) isn't working anymore (I've just changed the `paramName` (to match my paramName)).

Comment: Do you have a `messages.properties`?

Comment: Nope, but that makes no difference (I've tried it, same result)

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am having same problem. I have tried this link http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/81092-custom-login-page-and-localization but no success.

Comment: @Vikas Vats: unfortunately not... :(

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation of Spring Security...

> Spring Security relies on Spring’s localization support in order to actually lookup the appropriate message. In order for this to work, you have to make sure that the locale from the incoming request is stored in Spring’s org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder. Spring MVC’s DispatcherServlet does this for your application automatically, **but since Spring Security’s filters are invoked before this, the LocaleContextHolder needs to be set up to contain the correct Locale before the filters are called. You can either do this in a filter yourself (which must come before the Spring Security filters in web.xml) or you can use Spring’s RequestContextFilter**. Please refer to the Spring Framework documentation for further details on using localization with Spring.

**Solution:** add a CustomLocaleFilter and register it before the SecurityFilters